# Progress 4GL automation in Java

Tags: java, automation, progress-4gl

I am working on a project where the basic requirement is to automate the workflow of an application written in Progress 4GL deployed on Unix box using the Java.

I need some help to know if there is any existing Java API or tool which can help me to automate the Progress-written (Keyboard driven) applications.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I have used java.awt.Robot API to automate few screens of the application.

Answer (score 0):

For such an API to be more helpful than java.awt.Robot or something like TCL/Expect it would probably need to be specific to the application.  Some Progress applications (Such as mfg/pro and Epicor for example) have defined APIs that you could work with.  But without knowing what application this is it is impossible to say.

Java applications can also interact with Progress-4GL through an interface called "proxy gen".  But, again, that is going to be very specific to the application and not a generic tool like you seem to be looking for.